# Geth fails after move of freezer content to new SSD, sites gap in Ancient and leveldb

Tags: chaindata, freezer

I'm attempting to split my chaindata files across two Samsung T5 SSDs. Mounted the new SSD at /media/t5 and copied the 'ancient' chaindata subdirectory files with

```
cp -r /var/lib/goethereum/geth/chaindata/ancient /media/t5/ancient
```

changed group and file ownership of ancient and contents to geth
changed permissions on ancient directory to 755

Changed geth.service file:

```
ExecStart=geth  --http --syncmode fast --cache 1024  --datadir /var/lib/goethereum  --datadir.ancient /media/t5/ancient
```

Did a daemon-reload and restarted geth

Result:

> Fatal: Failed to register the Ethereum service: gap (#11992073) in the
> chain between ancients and leveldb

Should I have stopped geth before copying those files?
Was cp -r not the correct way to copy the directory?
Or is there some other step I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is the answer. I should have stopped geth, obviously, before attempting this. The good news was that after stopping it with

```
sudo systemctl stop geth
```

I was able to use rsync to update the destination directory, restart Geth, and all was good.

```
rsync -av --progress dir1/ dir2
```